# E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate . Can't install snap package manager

Tags: ubuntu, package, snapshot, package-managers, snap

When I'm trying to run

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

It shows the error as below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package snapd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate
```

How to resolve this and install snap store in ubuntu ?

I tried to consult official documentation of snap at :
`https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-ubuntu`

and it says:

```
Snap is pre-installed and ready to go on all recent releases of Ubuntu.

This means, if you’re running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) or later, including Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) and Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster), you don’t need to do anything.
```

But why isn't it in my system then !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above error is happening because APT Package Manager blocks the installation of snap packages.

To enable snap support, we have two options:

Option 1: Delete the nosnap.pref file in the directory /etc/apt/preferences.d by running the command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref
```

Option 2: Comment the three lines of code in the same file.

```
Package: snapd
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: -10
```

Now, install snapd:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

And then, you can install any snap apps:

```
sudo snap install <app-name>
```

Comment: `comment` - is it #?

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov yes it is. APT doesn't blocks snap by default but in-case the subject error occurs, it is this case.

Answer (score 0):

For me its worked very well! thanks people.

Comment: This is not answer, please use comments instead of answer area.